# Art book based on realistic "Frankenstein"?

Tags: story-identification, frankensteins-monster

I'm looking for a book based on Shelley's "Frankenstein".

The book was written as if it were a nonfiction text about Victor Frankenstein as a real, historical person. In a very dry, factual manner it recounts his life and studies, and then the creation of his monster with excerpts from his diary and notebooks. The book features drawings, purportedly by Frankenstein, of his research executed in a style appropriate to the time, mostly black & white charcoal sketches done in a loose but very detailed style, of equipment, anatomy, dissections and "life studies" of the creature.

I believe it came out in the 80's or early 90's. The format was hardback, and as noted it was heavily illustrated.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to take a guess that this is [The Secret Laboratory by Jeremy Kay](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/840698.The_Secret_Laboratory_Journals_of_Dr_Victor_Frankenstein). Goodreads describes it as:

> The ultimate companion to the world's most enduring and horrific Gothic novel. Realistic diary entries track the doctor's progress with his daring Promethean experiment, as 150 inspired, atmospheric, two-color illustrations draw readers deep into the castle laboratory.

I don't own the book, and I can't find a preview of it online, so this can only be a guess. However the descriptions of it that I've found on the Internet seem close to your description.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it is "The Frankenstein Diaries" by Rev. Hubert Venables, Viking Press, 1980).